# Python-docx how to set font spacing?

Tags: python, python-docx

How to set font spacing in python-docx or how to add element to w:rPr?
//<w:rPr>  <w:spacing w:val="200"/>  </w:rPr>

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question?? Like what you want to achieve.

Comment: The same question in Github:https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/243,  I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API support for this setting in `python-docx`.

Adding a `<w:spacing>` element will work if that's what Word does, however the sequence in which child elements appear is, in general, significant in WordprocessingML (the XML schema .docx files adhere to). If you don't get the `w:spacing` element in the right order among the `w:rPr` child elements or you add one when one is already there, you'll trigger a repair error.

So you need something like this:

```
def run_set_spacing(run, value: int):
    """Set the font spacing for `run` to `value` in twips.

    A twip is a "twentieth of an imperial point", so 1/1440 in.
    """

    def get_or_add_spacing(rPr):
        # --- check if `w:spacing` child already exists ---
        spacings = rPr.xpath("./w:spacing")
        # --- return that if so ---
        if spacings:
            return spacings[0]
        # --- otherwise create one ---
        spacing = OxmlElement("w:spacing")
        rPr.insert_element_before(
            spacing,
            *(
                "w:w",
                "w:kern",
                "w:position",
                "w:sz",
                "w:szCs",
                "w:highlight",
                "w:u",
                "w:effect",
                "w:bdr",
                "w:shd",
                "w:fitText",
                "w:vertAlign",
                "w:rtl",
                "w:cs",
                "w:em",
                "w:lang",
                "w:eastAsianLayout",
                "w:specVanish",
                "w:oMath",
            ),
        )
        return spacing

    rPr = run._r.get_or_add_rPr()
    spacing = get_or_add_spacing(rPr)
    spacing.set("val", str(value))
```

Then you would call this for each run that needs that setting like so:

```
run_set_spacing(run, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by scanny, It did not work. But the output document XML <w:spacing val="200"> is close to the right format.
The right format is <w:spacing w:val="200">

Try this

```
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

spacing.set(qn('w:val'), str(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've set the spacing in a new document for 'Normal' text.
of course this answer takes advantage of old replies

```py
    # create a new Document
    doc = Document()
    style = doc.styles['Normal']
    spacing = OxmlElement("w:spacing")
    spacing.set(qn('w:val'), str("-12"))
    
    style.font._element.rPr.insert_element_before(
        spacing,
        *("w:w", "w:kern", "w:position", "w:sz", "w:szCs", "w:highlight", "w:u", "w:effect", "w:bdr", "w:shd",
          "w:fitText", "w:vertAlign", "w:rtl", "w:cs", "w:em", "w:lang", "w:eastAsianLayout", "w:specVanish", "w:oMath",
          ),
    )
```